# windows process waiting for lsass

Tags: windows-7, clearcase

My company is using clearcase on a linux server and the development environment under linux and windows 7.
The windows 7 machines are for snapshot only.
the problem we have is windows only.

For each clearcase command under windows, there is a lot of latency. 
We noticed the process lsass.exe when  we do  ressource monitor/analyze wait chain  of cleartool process.
The wait of cleartool on lsass cuase a latency going from 50 sec to 1 minute

The problem does not occur for all users and not all the time.
when the problem does not occur the cleartool process has no process on analyze wait chain.
We have clearcase 8 set on the server and clients with version 7 or 8 .

We are pretty sure it is not a clearcase problem.

I would like some information about lsass and see what could cause the wait on lsass.exe

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: The related question I am seing seems to say otherwise

Answer (score 1):

lsass is the [Local Security Authority Subsystem Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Security_Authority_Subsystem_Service), is a process in Microsoft Windows operating systems that is responsible for enforcing the security policy on the system.

I have seen issues in the pass when an Anti-Virus was analyzing ClearCase views.
Try and deactivate as many process/service as possible in order to see if cleartool commands still experience this kind of latency.

Answer (score 0):

ClearCase makes a LOT of calls to your domain controller(s). I have seen some "interesting" performance issues if the communication is sporadically or completely interrupted.

Can you explain where all the major players are in relation to one another? Including, but not limited to:

- Windows domains. If there are multiple Windows domains, are they all AD domains in the same forest?
- Domain controllers.
- Clients.
- VOB/View servers.
- License servers? Type of licenses served (Classic Atria/Classic Flexnet/Tokens)
- Are there multiple license servers in use? (if using FlexNet/Tokens)

A key heads-up is that there were some issues a couple of years back with the permissions on ...\ClearCase\var\cache on Windows. It could cause some pretty serious performance issues if users don't have the rights to create files and write to them here.

You may also want to take a network trace of one of these updates. If you see anything that flat doesn't belong (NetBIOS name broadcasts for your DOMAIN name would be one, as this is a last resort to get a DC address), you may need to do some investigation...